# When I am running playbook its showing Variable not defined

Tags: networking, ansible

```yaml
- hosts: switch
  connection: network_cli
  become_method: enable
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
   - name: vlan_id
     prompt: enter the vlan_id
     private: no

  vars:
    cli:
       username: admin
       password: int123$%^

    vlans:
      100: "CORE"
      200: "MONITORING"
      300: "ACCESS"
      400: "GUEST_WIFI"

    ansible_buffer_read_timeout: 2
  tasks:
    - name: "creating the vlans"
      ios_vlans:
       config:
       - vlan_id: "{{ vlan_id }}"
         mtu: 700
         state: active
         shutdown: disabled

      register: show_vlan

    - debug:
        var: show_vlan.stdout_lines
```

Output:

```
enter the vlan_id: 11

PLAY [switch] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [creating the vlans] **************************************************************************************************************************************** changed: [172.16.1.252]

TASK [debug] 
ok: [172.16.1.252] => show_vlan.stdout_lines: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

PLAY RECAP 172.16.1.252 : ok=2 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Comment: enter the vlan_id: 11
PLAY [switch] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [creating the vlans] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.16.1.252]

TASK [debug] 
ok: [172.16.1.252] =>
  show_vlan.stdout_lines: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
PLAY RECAP 
172.16.1.252               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: debug just show_vlan and display result, for me you dont have the key stdout_lines existing

Comment: Debugging the complete registered variable `show_vlan` takes less time than writing the above question and gives an immediate answer (i.e. there is no `stdout_lines` key in that variable)

Answer (score 1):

ios_vlans module does not have stdout_lines key in it's return values. Please check the [documention here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_vlans_module.html#return-values)
so debug show_lan

```
    - debug:
        var: show_vlan
```